# SingleSignOn using Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have two applications as below

Application1 contains Login functionality.after login i have a Link to open Application2.

Application2 is providing some operations after login.

Now My requirement is navigating to application 2 home page if we navigate from application1.

Ex: Opening FB messanger from Facebook application no login required.

I need same functionality in my applications.

Kindly suggest me how to implement this functionality in Worklight

Answer (score 0):

MobileFirst provides Device SSO functionality.

See here for v7.1: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_device_single_sign_on.html

See here for v8.0:https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/device-sso/

The recommendation is to use v8.0